# How to add a Maven archetype to Github?

Tags: maven, github, maven-3

I have developed my custom project using Maven and I'd like to share it to the Community. Is it possible to drop it on GitHub so that it can be downloaded from there (and used in the create-archetype command).
Thanks
Mark

Comment: The best thing for a project and in particular for a community is to get it into maven central.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article may give a little help: http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/

Yes it is possible. All artifacts and the archetype catalog can be put there. People will have to add it as repository in their projects but it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically upload the maven artifacts for your project as part of your deploy process by using the steps in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14013645/82156